# document.execCommand('copy') not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

On Chrome only `document.execCommand('copy')` returns true but does not copy the text, it clears the clipboard.

I can't find anyone who's had the same problem, there are a lot of similar questions but please don't mark this as a duplicate unless it really is.

- I am calling `selection.removeAllRanges()` before `selection.addRange()`.
- `selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()` returns a fragment containing the correct text
- The text in the textarea doesn't appear selected
- If I call `textarea.select()` before `document.execCommand('copy')` the text appears selected and gets coppied to the clipboard. I don't want to do this because it focuses the textarea and causes the page to scroll.
- Tested on Chrome 61 and 63, MacOS
- Working in Safari

Here's my code (used within a click event listener)
https://codepen.io/jakecr/pen/XVXvKz

```
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.textContent = 'coppied text';
document.body.appendChild(textarea);

var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(textarea);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);

// DOESN'T WORK WITHOUT THIS
// textarea.select();

console.log(selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
console.log('copy success', document.execCommand('copy'));
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am not really clear as to what really happens here...

It seems there is a mismatch as to what should be used between the `value` and the `textContent` properties of your textarea.
Chrome seems to always use `value`, while Firefox uses `textContent`.

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  const txt = document.createElement('textarea');
  document.body.appendChild(txt);
  txt.value = 'from value'; // chrome uses this
  txt.textContent = 'from textContent'; // FF uses this
  var sel = getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(txt);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  if(document.execCommand('copy')){
    console.log('copied');
  }
  document.body.removeChild(txt);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Copy!</button>
<textarea>You can paste here

</textarea>
```

Since chrome doesn't look at the `textContent` property, *[Range#selectNodeContents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents)* will select nothing on this browser...

However, you can use *[Range#selectNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNode)* which should return the same result in this case, and will workaround the issue.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.textContent = 'copied text';
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);

  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();
//  range.selectNodeContents(textarea);
  range.selectNode(textarea);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  console.log('copy success', document.execCommand('copy'));
  selection.removeAllRanges();

  document.body.removeChild(textarea);
  
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">copy</button>
<textarea>You can paste here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 35):

For people reading this question in 2020, if you're having trouble with `document.execCommand('copy')`, you may want to try using the Clipboard API.

Per [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard):

> There are two ways browser extensions can interact with the system
> clipboard: the Document.execCommand() method and the modern
> asynchronous Clipboard API.

Also per [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), `document.execCommand()` is now obsolete:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
> its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
> avoid using it.

With the Clipboard API, writing text to the clipboard is particularly easy:

```
const textToCopy = 'Hello there!'
navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy)
  .then(() => { alert(`Copied!`) })
  .catch((error) => { alert(`Copy failed! ${error}`) })
```

More info:

[Mozilla's discussion of the two clipboard systems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

[Google's discussion of the two clipboard systems](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi)

[Another good discussion of the Clipboard API](https://alligator.io/js/async-clipboard-api/)

[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_writetext)

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking everywhere for this!

Comment: So there's no centralized way using vanilla javascript to do this?

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this like so:  onClick='navigator.clipboard.writeText("CopyMe")'

Comment: today, in May 2021, this is the only way that works in the current version of EDGE.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for other content types (like text/html).

Comment: security reason

Answer (score 2):

I have found that you can't dynamically insert a input field, insert some text, and then copy it to the clipboard.  I was able to copy text from an existing input tag.

Comment: The code above dynamically inserts an input field and it does work for me

Comment: I was adding a hidden input field and I should amend what I found.  What I ended up doing is appending a visible input field, putting in the contents, `execCommand('copy')`, then hide the input element.

Comment: This helped me quite a bit. I had an input in a hidden div that I was changing the content on dynamically. Had to set the div to visible while doing the select or it didn't work.

Comment: The legacy method (hack, pretty much) to dynamically create the DOM input element and copy from that, continues to work for us in a lot of contexts, but have found with certain UI frameworks (possibly what @Dr_Derp also describes) other events or focus/timing seem to interfere, also versus where we attach the element. The navigator.clipboard API has saved us here where we are only supporting recent browsers.