# copy to clipboard in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, clipboard

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms; // step 1

namespace School.Admin
{

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [STAThreadAttribute] // step 2
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText("Why it did not copy the words"); //step 3
    }
}
```

}

the erorr is:

**The current thread must be set to Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Make sure the Main function is checked**

Comment: You should elaborate a bit on what are you trying to do. And what clipboard you are trying to set text to (server side? client side?)

Comment: ASP.NET is server-side. You would copy to clipboard on the client using JS. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: Web servers are configured to handle multiple requests. A clipboard is unique to the machine in question. What precisely is it you are trying to achieve here? Because this sounds like a bad idea regardless of how to implement it.

Comment: If you ever find yourself referencing System.Windows.Forms in an ASP.NET project, you need to stop and reevaluate what you're doing. That namespace is for Windows Forms, which is a completely different framework than ASP.NET. There are extremely few situations where it makes sense to use anything from Windows Forms in an ASP.NET  project, and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use a piece of js

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Copy to Clipboard</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function CopyToClipboard(myID) 
         {
              var copyText = document.getElementById(myID);

              /* Select the text field */
              copyText.select();
              copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

              /* Copy the text inside the text field */
              document.execCommand("copy");
         }
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Copy Text Box Text to Clip board" OnClientClick="CopyToClipboard('TextBox1')" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec. 2021 - Here's a working example using jQuery / js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CopyToClipboard() 
    {
        var copyText = $('[id$="txt_Output"]').val(); // txt_Output is the id of your textbox to copy from. Could refactor this to pass as a parameter as well if desired.

        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)
          .then(() => { alert('Copied to clipboard.') })
          .catch((error) => { alert('Copy failed. Error: ${error}') })
    }

</script>
```

I pieced together some answers from this thread to help me arrive at the above code: [document.execCommand('copy') not working on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879184/document-execcommandcopy-not-working-on-chrome/47880284)